# Azure builds solution when I create pull request as draft

Tags: azure, azure-devops, pull-request

I have two project in my solution Model and Client:

[image: my solution]

I made some changes in Client. In Model I added comment before IndexProducts method in ctor of DataProvider class:

```
 public DataProvider()
    {
        //IndexProducts();
    }
```

Then I created Pull request as draft. And then I removed my comment, commit and pushed changes. When I Publish pull request, azure shows DataProvider class in Files
[image: pull request]

But there is no changes in DataProvider class. And also azure builds all solution (Client and Model project). Why it thinks that I changed DataProvider class?